# How to add a row in a certain observation and then print the first 5 rows?

Tags: r

I am trying to add the a row of data to a data frame in the `third` observation spot but the data frame has 10 variables and I am only adding 7. I was instructed R would automatically make the others NA but that wasn't the case - it repeated the info so now the 11th observation says "Pike."

I've tried:

```
COVID %>%
  add_row(COVID, county = "Pike", confirmed = 1392, confirmed_delta = 10, deaths = 30, recovered = 103, recovered_delta = 2, active_delta = 1, .before = 4) %>%
  head(5)
```

and

```
head(add_row(COVID, county = "Pike", confirmed = 1392, confirmed_delta = 10, deaths = 30, recovered = 103, recovered_delta = 2, active_delta = 1, .before = 4), 5)
```

Add a row to the COVID data set with the following information and place it as the 3rd observation. Print the first 5 rows with the newly added row:
`county` = Pike
`confirmed` = 1392
`confirmed_delta` = 10
`deaths` = 30
`recovered` = 103
`recovered_delta` = 2
`active_delta` = 1

Is there a way to place it in the third index with only the 7 variables and the others be NA?

Comment: `add_row()` has `.before` and `.after` arguments to specify row placement.

Comment: I can't find anything on those two arguments. Do you have a source for them or their syntax?

Comment: It's in the documentation - see `?tibble::add_row`.  You use it like `add_row(COVID, ... <other args>, .after = 2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use base R , let's build demo data.frame

```r
covid <- data.frame(
  country = c("usa" , "fr" , "en" , "eg" , "ua"),
  confirmed = c(130 , 231 , 432 , 233, 323),
  confirmed_delta =  c(4, 3, 2, 4, 3),
  deaths = c(4, 3, 2, 4, 2),
  recovered = c(12, 32, 2, 3, 2),
  recovered_delta = 1:5,
  active_delta = 5:1
)



covid3 <- data.frame(country = "Pike", confirmed = 1392, confirmed_delta = 10, deaths = 30, recovered = 103, recovered_delta = 2, active_delta = 1)

covid <- rbind(covid[1:2 ,] , covid3 , covid[3:(ncol(covid)-2),] , make.row.names = F )


head(covid)
#>   country confirmed confirmed_delta deaths recovered recovered_delta
#> 1     usa       130               4      4        12               1
#> 2      fr       231               3      3        32               2
#> 3    Pike      1392              10     30       103               2
#> 4      en       432               2      2         2               3
#> 5      eg       233               4      4         3               4
#> 6      ua       323               3      2         2               5
#>   active_delta
#> 1            5
#> 2            4
#> 3            1
#> 4            3
#> 5            2
#> 6            1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I tried the ```COVID[3, ] <- c(county = "Pike", confirmed = 1392, confirmed_delta = 10, deaths = 30, recovered = 103, recovered_delta = 2, active_delta = 1)```
but then run into the issue that the original data frame has 10 variables and my new data only has 7

Comment: i updated the solution to not overwrite the 3rd row , thanks  @Ritchie Sacramento